# Como puedo obtener el año actual usando Jade en .vue (Proyecto web)

Tags: javascript, web

Hola estoy desarrollando un proyecto web y deseo que en el copyright me salga la fecha en la que se inicio la empresa y el año actual..

```
<template lang='jade'>
// Footer
footer#footer.footer
.container
  .row
.footer-wrapper
      .col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
        .footer-brand
img(src='assets/images/logo-white.png', alt='logo')
      .col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
.copyright
          p
 a(href='https://www.easycryptocoins.info/')  Easycryptos
            script.
#{(" © 2018 - " + new Date().getFullYear())}
| . All rights reserved.
  </template>
```

Al ejecutar este codigo obtengo esta respuesta

Easycryptos< © 2018 - 2019>. All rights reserved.

Alguien que me ayude ya que lo que espero es que me muestre   Easycryptos © 2018 - 2019. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario poner el `script.`. Simplemente con

```
a(href='https://www.easycryptocoins.info/')  Easycryptos #{(" © 2018 - " + new Date().getFullYear())} . All rights reserved.
```

Incluso es más sencillo de esta manera

```
a(href='https://www.easycryptocoins.info/')  Easycryptos  © 2018 - #{(new Date().getFullYear())} . All rights reserved.
```

Comment: Gracias por la cooperación este código " a(href='https://www.easycryptocoins.info/')  Easycryptos  © 2018 - #{(new Date().getFullYear())} . All rights reserved. " 
si me ayudó pero todo me sale como un enlace, es decir en el código inicial estaba para que solo easycryptos al dar click abriera una página web especifica, y el resto como texto normal.

ahora todo se me ha convertido en un enlace.

Comment: Puedes utilizar una etiqueta `span` o un `p`.
`span #[a(href='https://www.easycryptocoins.info/')  Easycryptos]  © 2018 - #{(new Date().getFullYear())} . All rights reserved.`

Comment: Hola amigo sigo sin poder, podrías ayudarme en serio no me da.Si utilizo la etiqueta p que queda escrito en dos lineas una encima de la otra.

Comment: El código funciona correctamente, testearlo [aquí](https://cfjedimaster.github.io/webdemos/pugclient/)